# Возвратные последовательности или рекуррентные уравнения?

Tags: математика

Как решать уравнения такого вида : `f(n) = 2*f(n-1)+n*f(n-2) ?`

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что он не имеет отношения к программированию или системному администрированию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Глухов, Елизаров, Нечаев, Алгебра Том 2

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, это: [Лекции по дискретной математике](http://mech.math.msu.su/department/dm/dmmc/EDU/DM07.pdf), параграф 3.